# Функция вычисления возраста (как сделать наоборот)

Tags: php

Чтобы на входе был возраст, а на выходе год, месяц и день рождения.

```
function calc_age( $byear, $bmonth, $bday )
{
    $date = new DateTime("$byear-$bmonth-$bday");
    $now = new DateTime();
    $interval = $now->diff($date);
    echo $interval->y;
}
```

Comment: просите у клиента его возраст (год, месяц, день) и вычитаете из сегодня. У человека 364 дня в году возраст в годах один и тот же..

Comment: @Виктор нет, мне нужно наоборот. Узнать дату из возраста. Т.е. на входе 35 лет допустим, а мы получаем 1982, месяц и день (сегодняшние)